# Github commits aren't verified

Tags: git, github

For some reason my github commits aren't registering properly.

Of the ten commits from this project from July, it only recognizes two of them as verified and coming from myself:

https://github.com/ZalmanKelber/WikiScraper/commits/master

In this recent project, none of my commits are verified (in the most recent commits I've changed my user.name setting in my local git configuration to match my Github account):

https://github.com/ZalmanKelber/FilterImageUpload/commits/main

When I type in `git config user.email` on my terminal, it lists the correct email address associated with my Github account.  Why aren't my commits recognized?  As a result of this, my contributions graph looks empty.

Comment: Some symptoms from on their site of why contributions not showing up, https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted. Might be good to reference this.

Comment: Well GitHub clearly doesn't know who "Alex Kelber" is. And it isn't just the name; you'll notice that in the two verified one, "ZalmanKelber" is a _link_ to you. So clearly you were using the correct identity for those two.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a matter of the wrong user.name/user.email used when doing the commit.

If I display the author/committer name and email, I get:

```
D:\git\tests\WikiScraper>git log --pretty="format:%aN %ae %cN %ce"
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Zalman Kelber 62047666+ZalmanKelber@users.noreply.github.com GitHub noreply@github.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Zalman Kelber 62047666+ZalmanKelber@users.noreply.github.com GitHub noreply@github.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com Alex Kelber ZalmanKelber@gmai.com
```

- The name is wrong:

  ```
  Alex Kelber 
  # instead of
  Zalman Kelber
  ```
- The email is wrong:

  ```
  ZalmanKelber@gmai.com  
  # instead of
  ZalmanKelber@gmail.com
  ```

And if you have [set your GitHub  email to private](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github), the email would need to be:

```
<project-name>@users.noreply.github.com
```

Comment: thanks!  I got it to work yesterday by changing the email to the noreply github email -- I somehow missed the "gmai" typo.